# how to add OR conditions in Scopes func

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

in MySQL :

```
db.Scopes(MyScope).Where("age > ?",30).Find(&user)
```

How can I get like as below statement in MyScope func :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE age > 30 AND ( xxx OR xxx )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried but I guess it will work like this

```
db.Scopes(MyScope).Where("age > ?",30).Where(db.Where("name = ?",name).Or("name = ?",name))
```

It should generate following sql

```
select * from user where age>30 and (name ='XX' or name='YY')
```

For more information, you can check [this](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#group_conditions) link